# Find postion inside the output of tokenize()

Tags: xpath

Say I have the following:

```
<data>
   <fruits>apples, bananas, cherries, oranges</fruits> 
</data>
```

With

```
tokenize(//fruits,',')
```

I get the expected 4 fruits. If I'm interested in `cherries`

```
tokenize(//fruits,',')[3]
```

will get me "cherries".

But what if I needed to do the reverse - can I find the position of `cherries` (i.e., `3`) within the output of `tokenize()`? I tried playing with various combinations of `count()`, `contains()` and `position()` but could come up with nothing remotely relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`index-of`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_index-of.html) if it is available in your Xquery/XPath processor like this:

```
index-of(tokenize(//fruits,',\s*'), 'cherries')
```

[Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Cdata%3E%0A%20%20%20%3Cfruits%3Eapples%2C%20bananas%2C%20cherries%2C%20oranges%3C%2Ffruits%3E%20%0A%3C%2Fdata%3E&=&extract=index-of(tokenize(%2F%2Ffruits%2C%27%2C%5Cs*%27)%2C%20%27cherries%27)%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A&=index-of(tokenize(%2F%2Ffruits%2C%27%2C%5Cs*%27)%2C%20%27cherries%27)&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=xml&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xpath3.0)

I have modified the split pattern to trim leading whitespace in subsequent tokens.

Edit: supputuri

You can see the token output which have the whitespace between `,` and the string in the below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: `index-of`! Something else to learn... Thanks. Quick followup question: why was `\s*` necessary?

Comment: `\s*` is similar to `trim()/strip()` which will remove the whitespaces. You have to trim the token otherwise the comparison string does not match, and you don't get the index though it's there in the list.

Comment: Thanks, supputuri already explained the crucial part. Basically, `',\s*'` is a regular expression used for splitting by [fn:tokenize](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_tokenize.html). This should give you the idea https://regex101.com/r/1vHEmD/1

Comment: @supputuri and wp78de - so it should also work with `index-of(tokenize(normalize-space(//fruits),','),'cherries')`, right? But it doesn't seem to.

Comment: It doesn't work without `\s*` in your case because you have a white space between `,` and `cherries` like `, cherries`. That's the reason why you have to trim the string ` cherries` before as part of `index-of` method.

Comment: Check the updated answer with the screenshot, which will show the white spaces at the starting of the string. You have to trim those whitespace when using `index-of`.

Comment: @supputuri - Got it! So it seems that stripping the whitespaces with this `index-of(tokenize(translate(//fruits,' ',''),','),'cherries')` should also work.

Comment: I would not suggest using the `translate` as it will remove the space between the words too (not only leading whitespaces). Think about `jack fruit` is part of your data and if you try with `index-of(tokenize(translate(//fruits,' ',''),','),'jack fruit')` you don't get the index.

Comment: So I would recommend using `\s*` for the trimming always.